# How do I access the last command from a zsh function?

Tags: zsh, zsh-alias

I'd like to do something like this:

```sh
function invim () {
  vim $(!!)
}
```

However when I run it, it says:
`invim:1: command not found: !!`

I assume this is because `!!` is an interactive shell expansion not available in noninteractive scripts/functions. In bash I could use the `history` command to accomplish this, but when I tried to use it, it seems to hijack my readline and not allow up-arrow completion to work anymore.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You could read directly from the history file. See [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111718/command-history-in-zsh) discussing the niceties of identifying the right file to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Gairfowl's answer with the associative array, I was able to formulate an appropriate solution:

```sh
function invim {                                              
    vim $(bash -c ${history[@][1]})            
}
```

Here's how it works:

1. `${history[@][1]}` is the text of the latest command, for example, `find . -type f -name "*.txt"`
2. Run that command in a shell using `bash -c`
3. The resulting stdout is captured by the enclosing `$()`, and is then passed to vim as the filename(s) to edit. There are no enclosing quotes here to allow for multiple line outputs to all be opened.

Comment: Try `vim "$(${=history[@][1]})"`, see if it works for your commands (embedded spaces could be a challenge).

Answer (score 2):

(nb: this is not a complete answer; see comments and https://stackoverflow.com/a/70285039/9307265)

---

Recent commands are available in the `history` associative array, so this should be similar to the function in your question:

```
function invim {
    vim ${history[@][1]}
}
```

The `history[@]` expansion gets the commands from the associative array, while `[1]` references the first item, which is guaranteed to be the most recent.

But that may not do exactly what you're looking for.  Unlike `bash`, `zsh` doesn't re-parse variable expansions as words, so executing the function right after calling `foo --opt` will result in an attempt to edit a file named `foo --opt`, which probably doesn't exist.  We can get just the first word by using word expansion with `${=...}`, converting it an array with the `(A)` parameter expansion flag, and adding another `[1]` index operator.

Also, in many cases this function would only find a file in that's in the current directory. With the `:c` modifier, the function can search the `PATH` and find the source file.

Putting it all together:

```
function invim {
    vim ${${(A)=history[@][1]}[1]:c}
}
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps my question was unclear; I want to edit the file(s) that correspond to the stdout of the most recently run command, not the files that correspond to the command itself, if that makes sense

Comment: Ahh - I missed that completely.  I'll add a note, but leave this in place.

Comment: Note that the `${${(A)=cmd_str}[1]}` trick only works for the first parameter (in most cases) because it doesn’t deal with quotation or spaces; in other words, if `$cmd_str` is something like `vim file\ with\ spaces`, then `${${(A)=cmd_str}[2]}` gives ``file\``, which is typically not so useful. The `(z)` flag can help this case.