# Use Dollar and parenthesis inside string

Tags: zsh

Trying to define this alias in *zsh*
I think the problem is that inside the string, **$(...)** doesn't work properly

```
alias ss='sudo $(history -p \!\!)'
```

The output is the usage of sudo

```
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] 
....
```

Comment: Use a function, not an alias

Comment: Did you try `history -p \!\!` on the command line? It does not do anything. Probably you meant `history !!`, but, according to the zsh man page: _History  expansion  allows you to use words from previous command lines in the command line **you are typing**_, so it does not work inside an alias or function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access the last command from a zsh function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70282669/how-do-i-access-the-last-command-from-a-zsh-function)

Comment: @user1934428 kind of, I think this solution my friend provided in the EDIT is better

Comment: If it works, post it as an answer (it is OK to answer your own question). Also add some explanation for how it works.  Since `fc`  is a builtin command of zsh, you find it documented in the man-page.

Answer (score 0):

For listing the history on *zsh* according to [this](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-fc) doc:

`fc -ln <number>`

the modifiers:
`-n` - removes the line counter
`<number>` - starts the history from this number historically (-1 is the last used)

for the purpose of the alias the solution is:
`alias ss='sudo $(fc -ln -1)'`

Special thanks to @ericnb